# Mysql sum up the values of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SLNO UpazillaID CityArea VillageArea CharArea HillArea HaorArea TotalArea Year
6       1           11      44          11      11        11       11     2014
7       2           12      13          14      13        13       13     2013
```

I want to sum CityArea, VillageArea, CharArea, HillArea, HaorArea, TotalArea Where UpazillaID in 1,2.

Comment: You can make use of MySQL's aggregate `SUM()` function http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/

Answer (score 1):

Select (column1 + column2 + column3....) as totalcolumn. This will give you the sum per row.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (SUM(CityArea)+SUM(VillageArea)+SUM(CharArea)+SUM(CharArea)+SUM(CharArea)+SUM(TotalArea)) 
AS Total
FROM your_table
WHERE UpazillaID = 1
```